# Most efficient way of changing the value of a CGPoint in a CGPoint array?

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsarray

I have constructed a CG Point array as follows:

```
NSMutableArray *_startPositions = [NSMutableArray array];
[_startPositions addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(0.0, 0.0)]];
[_startPositions addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(0.0, 0.0)]];
```

How can i most efficiently change the x and y values of the points in the array?

If I retrieve the value using:

```
CGPoint myPoint0 = [[_startPositions objectAtIndex:0] CGPointValue];
```

I get back a copy of the point. How can I change the x and y values of the CGPoints in the array? I could remove the CGPoint at any position and replace it with one with the correct x,y values, but is there a more efficient way?

Comment: It depends on your usage pattern. If you are often passing `_startPositions` to an API that accepts an `NSArray` of `CGPoint`, you might try using `[ _startPositions replaceObjectAtIndex:withObject: ]` and updating the points that way. If instead you edit the points much more often than you send `_startPositions` to your API, create a C array of `CGPoint` that you keep updated, then generate the `_startPositions` as needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use C array instead of NSMutableArray. If required use C++ STL collection classes such as std::vector or other C/C++ collection library. In this way, you can manipulate the array content without any Obj-C method call.

Comment: You were right. I was over thinking it. It is a series of localized operations, so c/c++ sytle arrays are fine

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you create your own class as

.h

```
@interface MyPoint : NSObject {
    CGPoint point;
}
@property (nonatomic,assign) CGPoint point;
@end
```

.m

```
@implementation MyPoint
@synthesize point;
@end
```

Then add your `MyPoint` Object in your array.
Change it like

```
MyPoint *myPoint = [_startPositions objectAtIndex:0];
myPoint.point = myPoint0;
```

Answer (score 0):

From the docs:

> `NSValue` objects are always immutable.

So your only option here is to create a new `NSValue` to replace the old one when the `CGPoint` value changes. If you are looking for a more efficient way to store an array of `CGPoints`, then a C array is the easiest and fastest way to go.

Answer (score 0):

If you are changing just the 'x' or 'y' value of CGPoint `point`, you can do this:

`((CGPoint *)&point)->x += dx;`

or

`((CGPoint *)&point)->y += dy;`